# InvocationTargetException in Java Web Start applet/application

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, invocationtargetexception

For reference, I previously asked a question about an error with essentially converting my Java application to an applet. Well, I was suggested to try JavaWebStart, and I am still receiving problems with this way as well, so I decided to create a new question.

Here is the question I'm referencing: [java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception error in applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135069/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-error-in-applet/17135272)

I'm assuming I am assuming I have some kind of structure wrong, of how to setup a JavaWebStart application, as I have tested my code locally as a jar file and had no errors running it.

Here is an example page:
http://fogest.com/java_example/

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The code I posted on the other question was only posted as it would help to see what the issue was. The other classes work fine, and I didn't include them. The actual compiled .class files were included in the jar though that is run from my sample webpage on my site. Anyway though, as I commented on your answer, you have solved my problem, so hopefully this issue you were having is no longer a big deal?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well in my previous question you were helping me on, the code was the focus of the issue, as I was trying to convert it to an applet. Using JavaWebStart is different though, and my code should not have caused the issue. The code was tested as an application before and worked fine, so I guessed that it would be fine here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your code *does* have a `main(String[] args)` as we were discussing in your last question.  As such, it might be as simple as changing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://fogest.com/java_example" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Launch applet with Web Start</title>
        <vendor>Foo Bar Inc.</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="physics.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc
         name="Physics" main-class="main.MainGame"
         width="300" height="200">
    </applet-desc>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

To something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://fogest.com/java_example" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Launch applet with Web Start</title>
        <vendor>Foo Bar Inc.</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="physics.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="main.MainGame">
    </application-desc>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

### Note

1. I did not validate either JNLP, but you should.  I wrote [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) for doing exactly that.
2. Swing GUIs should be created & updated on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) (especially the part on 'initial threads') for more details.
3. This is an SSCCE based on the frame.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainGame {
    public static final String NAME = "Physics - Projectile Motion Example";
    public static final int HEIGHT = 160;
    public static final int WIDTH = HEIGHT * 16 / 9;
    public static final int SCALE = 4;

    public MainGame() {
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(MainGame.NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        JPanel options = new JPanel();
        options.add(new JLabel("Options"));
        JPanel game = new JPanel();
        game.add(new JLabel("Game"));

        frame.setSize(new Dimension ( WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE ));

        frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(options, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. That modified JNLP you posted fixes the problem! The application opens and functions how it is suppose to now! Thanks for all your help Andrew! Also thanks for the suggestion of using SSCCE when posting code, I will be sure to try and do this with all my future questions! The example you gave using my code helped me see visually what you meant as well which is very helpful!